# JQcloud words overlap when convert to image

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

i am trying to convert **JQCloud** words to **PNG** by using **html2Canvas** library. After converting words overlap and change the their direction. The following image after converting.
 [image]

**My Javascript Code:**

```
 $('#save-image').click(function(){

        html2canvas($('#words_cloud'), 
         {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");       
                a.download = 'image.png';
                a.click();
            }
         });
        });
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, how did you resolved ?